# Iterating on database records to create attribute hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby Newbie here.  First off, this is more philosophical than practical, so if there is a better way to accomplish this, please tell.

I have a table that looks roughly like:

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ label  ║ value  ║ thing_id ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ color  ║ red    ║        1 ║
║  2 ║ size   ║ medium ║        1 ║
║  3 ║ weight ║ heavy  ║        1 ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

i query this and get a recordset for a particular thing.

```
thing_attributes = ThingAttributes.where(:thing_id => 1)
```

which results in a recordset of 5 or so rows from that table.  I'd like to be able to create a has that allows me to create the equivalent of `{"color" => "red", "size" => "medium", "weight" => "heavy" }`.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. I feel confused by your wording.

Comment: Sorry.  I think my title is perhaps misworded. I will try to clarify.

Comment: What exactly do you want this hash to be? An aggregation of every record's label? Should the table be one unified hash map? I mean, if you have 50 records, do you want a hash with 50 keys and 50 values? Will you accept multiple records with the same label (key) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, basically you are trying to imitate a schemaless database, because you want your different records to have different attributes. As long as you only have one custom attribute pr. record, this could work, but if your records have more attributes in difference than common, then you might want to consider having multiple models, look into the hstore datatype or look into a document database such as MongoDB.

## Update

Reading your question again, I think I have a better solution, so I have deleted the original one.

I'm going to call your ThingAttributes class what I think it is - a CustomAttribute class. Because each record represents one custom attribute. A Thing can have many (in your example five) custom attributes.

So you can do this:

```
class CustomAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
  attr_accessible :name, :value
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :custom_attributes
end
```

Now you can find a thing, by writing

```
my_thing = Thing.find(3)
```

You can then find it's custom_attributes, by writing

```
my_thing.custom_attributes
```

This will return an array of custom attributes. However, you are (for some reason) asking for a hash. This can be done too. In your Thing class, define this method:

```
def custom_attributes_hash
  custom_hash = {}
  self.custom_attributes.each do |attr|
    custom_hash[attr.name] = attr.value
  end
  custom_hash
end
```

Now, you may want to be able to set attributes in a convenient way as well. Define this on your Thing class.

```
def set_custom_attribute(name, value)
  return unless name.present? # Short circuits method if an empty string or nil is being used as name.
  custom_attribute = self.custom_attributes.find_by_name(name) # Attemps to find custom attribute with the name
  if custom_attribute.nil? # Executes block if no attribute was found
    return unless value.present? # Short circuits method if nil or empty string was passed as value
    self.custom_attributes.create(name: name, value: value) # Creates and saves new custom attribute
  else
    if value.present? # Updates existing attribute if passed is not an empty string or nil.
      custom_attribute.update_attribute(:value, value)
    else
      custom_attribute.destroy # Deletes custom attribute from DB if set_custom_attribute was called with a nil or empty value.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this looks like what i should be doing.  thanks very much! (especially after i reread my question and really asked it awkwardly - and you got what i was after)

Comment: I edited the answer, because I forgot about Ruby's lack of support for overloading. You can have an attr method which is both a getter and a setter, (with the second parameter being optional), but it has some pitfalls.

Comment: I have read your question again, and I don't think my solution will work, because you won't get the hash that you are asking for. Instead you will get an array of records, each with it's own attribute. You will be able to determine what custom attribute any of the record has, by calling the label accessor, but it's not good. I will edit the answer for a better solution.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to amend your answer to include hash, i'm still learning rails and this helps me very much!

Comment: Good luck with it. I have update the `add_custom_attribute` method to `set_custom_attribute`, because my previous implementation would allow you add multiple attributes with the same name. The new method checks if an existing attribute with the same name has already been set and updates it if so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure if i'm getting well, but try this:

```
my_thing = Thing.find(1)
my_thing.color
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for :

```
Thing_model.rb

thing = Thing.find(1)

 def #{self.label}
    return self.value
```